# Histogram with slider filter

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to create a histogram with a density plot combined in bokeh with a slider filter. Atm, I have the blocks to create a bokeh histogram with a density plot from another thread. I dont know how to create the callback function to update the data and rerender the plot.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

from numpy import histogram, linspace
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

pdf = gaussian_kde(df.hp)

x = linspace(0,250,50)

p = figure(plot_height=300)
p.line(x, pdf(x))

# plot actual hist for comparison
hist, edges = histogram(df.hp, density=True, bins=20)
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], alpha=0.4)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement callbacks in Bokeh:

- with [JS code](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html). In that case, the plot remains a standalone object, the constraint being you need to do any data manipulation within Javascript (there is a small caveat to that statement but not relevant here: `scipy` can't be called from such a callback)
- by having the callback executed in [Bokeh server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html), in which case you have the full arsenal of python available to you. The cost being, there's a bit more to plotting and distributing the graph than in the first case (but it's not difficult, see example).

Considering you need to refit the kde each time you change the filter condition, the second way is the only option (unless you want to do that in javascript...).

That's how you would do it (example with a filter on `cyl`):

```
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

from numpy import histogram, linspace
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

output_notebook()

def modify_doc(doc):
    x = linspace(0,250,50)

    source_hist = ColumnDataSource({'top': [], 'left': [], 'right': []})
    source_kde = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': []})

    p = figure(plot_height=300)
    p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source_kde)
    p.quad(top='top', bottom=0, left='left', right='right', alpha=0.4, source=source_hist)

    def update(attr, old, new):
        if new == 'All':
            filtered_df = df
        else:
            condition = df.cyl == int(new)
            filtered_df = df[condition]

        hist, edges = histogram(filtered_df.hp, density=True, bins=20)
        pdf = gaussian_kde(filtered_df.hp)

        source_hist.data = {'top': hist, 'left': edges[:-1], 'right': edges[1:]}
        source_kde.data = {'x': x, 'y': pdf(x)}

    update(None, None, 'All')

    select = Select(title='# cyl', value='All', options=['All'] + [str(i) for i in df.cyl.unique()])
    select.on_change('value', update)
    doc.add_root(column(select, p))

# To run it in the notebook:
plot = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))
show(plot)

# Or to run it stand-alone with `bokeh serve --show myapp.py`
# in which case you need to remove the `output_notebook()` call
# from bokeh.io import curdoc
# modify_doc(curdoc())
```

A few notes:

- this is made to be run in jupyter notebook (see the `output_notebook()` and the last uncommented two lines).
- to run it outside, comment the notebook lines (see above) and uncomment the last two lines. Then you can run it from the command line.
- `Select` will only handle `str` values so you need to convert in (when creating it) and out (when using the values: `old` and `new`)
- for multiple filters, you need to access the state of each `Select` at the same time. You do that by instantiating the `Select`s before defining the `update` function (but without any callbacks, yet!) and keeping a reference to them, access their value with `your_ref.value` and build your condition with that. After the `update` definition, you can then attach the callback on each `Select`.

Finally, an example with multiple selects:

```
def modify_doc(doc):
    x = linspace(0,250,50)

    source_hist = ColumnDataSource({'top': [], 'left': [], 'right': []})
    source_kde = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': []})

    p = figure(plot_height=300)
    p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source_kde)
    p.quad(top='top', bottom=0, left='left', right='right', alpha=0.4, source=source_hist)
    select_cyl = Select(title='# cyl', value='All', options=['All'] + [str(i) for i in df.cyl.unique()])
    select_ori = Select(title='origin', value='All', options=['All'] + [str(i) for i in df.origin.unique()])

    def update(attr, old, new):
        all = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
        if select_cyl.value == 'All':
            cond_cyl = all
        else:
            cond_cyl = df.cyl == int(select_cyl.value)
        if select_ori.value == 'All':
            cond_ori = all
        else:
            cond_ori = df.origin == int(select_ori.value)
        filtered_df = df[cond_cyl & cond_ori]

        hist, edges = histogram(filtered_df.hp, density=True, bins=20)
        pdf = gaussian_kde(filtered_df.hp)

        source_hist.data = {'top': hist, 'left': edges[:-1], 'right': edges[1:]}
        source_kde.data = {'x': x, 'y': pdf(x)}

    update(None, None, 'All')

    select_ori.on_change('value', update)
    select_cyl.on_change('value', update)

    doc.add_root(column(select_ori, select_cyl, p))
```

Comment: Thank you for your great response. To understand you correctly about the multiple fitlers because that is what I try to achieve right now. I define  the two selectors before the update as follows `select = Select(title='# cyl', value='All', options=['All'] + [str(i) for i in df.cyl.unique()]) ` and  `select_2 = Select(title="Car name", value="All", options['All'] + df.name.unique()`  and I replace the  `condition = df.cyl == int(new) ` line with   `condition = df[df.cyl ==  select.val & df.name == select_2.val] `

Comment: added an example. I used `origin` instead of `name` as the `name` is almost unique so a kde didn't really make sense on a `name`-filtered df.